# Image not displaying, but shows in Firebug

Tags: html, dom

I have a rather unique problem. I'm trying to get a logo to display, however it simply doesn't show - it will however show in Firebug as it should (i.e. hover over the image and it displays the preview).

I have tried absolute filepaths, relative filepaths and everything else under the sun. The logo sometimes appears for 2-3 seconds upon refresh then will simply vanish from the screen - I've never experienced a problem like this and find this truly mind-blowing.

Am i missing something obvious here?

Link: http://project.n8geeks.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because, for some reason, there was no default .htaccess file - not sure how or why that should effect the displaying of images, but that was the solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the link and it seems like its a web server configuration issue, since Chrome's Dev Tools said:

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://n8geeks.com/".

what you need to do is add the png MIMEtype to your web server configuration.

Comment: I'll chase up my host and see what they say - thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set Height attr for div .logo
With div Img you should set width and height.
I try set height 30px for div .logo. It works.

Comment: This didn't resolve the issue for me - are you sure it works for you? Perhaps the image just showed for a few seconds, like it did for me, then disappeared again?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a different image just to test? I have tried it (with firebug) and it seems to work.